# inserting Greek letters into PDF comments

Tags: pdf

I am using PDF comments lately for taking notes. One issue is that there are a lot of Greek letters to write down. I can't find a way to type Greek letters into PDF comments. Currently, I have to either

- type things like `\alpha \eta`  per Latex, which is quite cumbersome, or
- use PDF software such as Drawboard PDF that allow drawing the Greek letters pictorially, which generates a large amount of data in the comments.

Is there a PDF software that allows me to type Greek letters into PDF comments directly?

I googled around and only found this (unanswered) question: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1040867

I am primarily using Acrobat Reader DC in Windows. Ideally, I'd like a portable solution such that the generated PDF can be viewed on other computers without having to install fonts/language packs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the visual clutter of having `\alpha` in you comment rather than the effort of typing these macro names is the problem, an option would be on-the-fly conversion to unicode characters with an AutoHotkey script (Windows only, requires unicode-capable installation of Autohotkey). I created one some time back based on Emacs' "TeX" input method:

https://gist.github.com/kbauer/e8fee6514d124d5961f51fd7ba571bfd